# Crystal Report C# Page Header and Detail Section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have 2 Text objects in my Report. One is in the page header containing "Month" text. One is in the detail section where it displays data from my database which I formatted to be displayed horizontally. But I can't seem to find a way to make my two text objects align horizontally. Refer to this image.

[image]

Because if I put the page header text object into the detail section, this is what happens.

[image]

Related code on how I get values from my 2nd text object and display them in detail section.

```
     MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        String query = " Select username from users";

        MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapt.Fill(ds, "JODT");

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Found", "JobOrder");
            return;
        }

        joRpt.SetDataSource(ds);

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject root;
        root = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
            joRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[0];


        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = joRpt;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Go to Section expert of Page header and select check box `Underlay following sections` and check output